# complex analysis problems related to nalyticity......

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't even know how to start for the following problem. It would be highlt appreciated if you could help me.

Let $z_n=\frac{1}{n},\forall n\in\Bbb N$. If possible find $f\in H(\bar{B}_1(0))$ [H means analyticity] such that $\{f(z_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are given by each of the follwoing cases

(a) {0,1,0,1,.....}

(b) {$1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16}...$}

(c) {$0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}...$}

(d) {$\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}......$}

If not possible, explain why such an $f$ may not exist.

Comment: $f(z)=z^2$ for (b) and $f(z)=z$ for (c).

Comment: @Andres Caicedo, Could you please suggest me what should I do to make it a good question, I do not feel good about having a question which is on hold/closed.

Comment: @Did, Could you please suggest me what should I do to make it a good question, I do not feel good about having a question which is on hold/closed.

Comment: @Ivo Terek, Could you please suggest me what should I do to make it a good question, I do not feel good about having a question which is on hold/closed.

Comment: @amWhy, Could you please suggest me what should I do to make it a good question, I do not feel good about having a question which is on hold/closed.

Comment: @Alizter, Could you please suggest me what should I do to make it a good question, I do not feel good about having a question which is on hold/closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two options can be handled without considering the analyticity of $f(z)$.

For the last one, consider $g \in H(B_1(0))$ defined as
$$g(z) = f(z/(1+z))-f(z)$$
so that $g(1/2n)=0$ (show).

This feels "wrong" for an analytic function. My complex analysis is rusty, but according to wikipedia if the zeros of an analytic function have an accumulation point in a connected domain, then the function is identically zero.

So $f(z/(1+z))=f(z)$ (show).

Use the substitution $z \to z/(z+1)$ repeatedly to conclude that $f(z)$ is constant (show). Hint: $f(z) = f(\frac{z}{nz+1})$ for all $n>0$.

Comment: This is too complicated and uses the same fact as in @Arthur's post, but hey, it works. And you get to solve a functional equation.

Comment: So you are saying f(z) exists, but Arthur is saying does not. Am I right?

Comment: If $f(z)$ is constant and $f(1/2n)=1/n$...

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, I shall prove by abovementioned way that f(z) exists but not analytic and hence no analytic function exits.

Comment: Sure, but if you understand Arthur's proof you should do it that way. Do something similar, but with $f(z)-2z$, were you look at the zeros and see if they have an accumulation point.

Comment: You should really accept his and not mine.

Answer (score 4):

Is $\overline{B}_1(0)$ the closed unit disk?

In that case the first one is impossible because it has no limit as $z\to 0$, thus isn't continuous at $0$. The second one is solved by $f(z)=z^2$.

The third one is also impossible, because every point except the first would force the function to be $f(z)=z$ (remember, analytical functions are uniquely determined by their value on a converging sequence of points). But that doesn't match the first point.

The last one I is also impossible, by the same reasoning as the third one, only instead of ignoring the first term, you ignore every term of odd index.

Comment: @ Arthur Thank you very much.......I was thinking in a complicated way.

Comment: I figured out the fourth one, and it is impossible. The proof goes along the same lines as the third, only instead of the subsequence $\{z_{n+1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ you look at the subsequence $\{z_{2n}\}_{z=1}^\infty$. Yet again, you have a subsequence that obviously forces the function to be $f(z)=z$, and yet again, that function fails to work on the other points.